# Capturing results from a dynamic page

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, web-services, google-sheets

I was using javascript in google sheets, but I can use .net technology to solve this, if it is possible, since I don't see a way to do this in google sheets (yet).

I am wanting to capture page content from a site.
The information is not static.
Based on the parameters I pass, I will get a different result.

For example, https://www.hapag-lloyd.com/en/online-business/tracing/tracing-by-booking.html?blno=HLCUEUR181027806#

This returns page associated with Bill of Lading number HLCUEUR181027806, which I can then parse using ImportXML function of Google Sheets.

I can't seem to be able to use Google Sheet's ImportXML function, because it doesn't work with dynamic pages that change content based on parameter provided.

The question is, is this possible to do, by any means, using any technology, to programatically send a request for a dynamic page, wait for result to return, and capture the output of that, so that I can parse it, and find key information from it.

I have knowledge of .net, c#, and learning web development as well.

See related question:

[Trouble fetching date from ImportXML. Need options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429062/trouble-fetching-date-from-importxml-need-options)

Comment: I've reverted your edit which added your answer to the question. It's fine to answer your own question, but we know already from you accepting it that you're happy with your answer - no need to say so in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using autoit.  It is a free scriptig language.
This is the right technology for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a headless browser that can load the page and wait for it to render (the reason is javascript is rendering the page in client) then parse the html.

You can select any library from this page which supports .net [here](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers)

Your other option is looking at the traffic and using the private Api (Which is more efficient but can be harder)